# Adding a YouTube subscribe button in my website but gives this error

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-data-api

So I've been trying to add a subscribe button on my test website using this code that YouTube API V3 gave me:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCzfStpfCASIjJNK2xMNdJiw" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

But when I load the page it gives me these errors:

```
> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
> provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin
> ('null').                                     cb=gapi.loaded 0:49

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
> provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin
> ('null').                                     cb=gapi.loaded 0:48
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your snippet, and worked fine for me. All I did was swapped yours for mine for testing and it still worked.
I would take a guess that you are having a conflict with your code.
So try putting your script tag at the top as first call. And if that don't work, try de-activating other scripts to see which has the conflict.

Comment: I don't know what I did but suddenly it worked! thanks though.